# separator by not using width hack

Tags: html, css

I often do the width hack 49% and border 1px to do seperator for 2 column. It worked, just like the below demo. But is there any better way of doing it? I want to avoid this 49% hack, because when the viewport shrink to a larger or smaller size, it's obvious and the design will break.

```css
body{
    margin:0;
}
.left {
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
    width: 49%;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
}
.right {
    background: #eee;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigate" style="width: 170px;">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrow-set/512/previous_arrow_point_flat-128.png">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrow-set/512/next_arrow_point_flat-128.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
.left {
    background: #eee;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right:1px solid #333;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.right {
    background: #eee;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 44px;
    padding: 5px 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigate" style="width: 170px;">
    <div class="left">
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrow-set/512/previous_arrow_point_flat-128.png">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/arrow-set/512/next_arrow_point_flat-128.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/9/)**